# Adding inner join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to add another innerjoin to my sql query. I'm not good with SQL and got stuck:

```
select * 
  from applications 
  inner join all_applications on app.name = all_applications.application_id 
  where paid = true
```

and need to add,

```
inner join subscriptions on applications.subname_id = subscriptions.id
```

How do make the query work without error?

edit: thanks, used wrong ref to app name

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Just add it? `select * from applications inner join stat_applications on applications.id = stat_applications.application_id inner join subscriptions on applications.subscription_id = subscriptions.id   where enabled = true`?

Comment: Do *not* vandalize your own posts.

Comment: Can you let us know what the specific error was?

Answer (score 0):

Add join under another inner join

```
select * 
from applications 
  inner join stat_applications on applications.id = stat_applications.application_id
  inner join subscriptions on applications.subscription_id = subscriptions.id 
where enabled = true
```

Comment: What error did you get? Please remove where condition and try again.

Comment: My guess is "enabled" exists in multiple tables.

Comment: May be don't have enabled column in three tables

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from applications 
     inner join 
      stat_applications on applications.id = stat_applications.application_id 
     inner join 
      subscriptions on applications.subscription_id = subscriptions.id
     where applications.enabled = true
```